# gcov -r generates no gcov file

Tags: c++, cmake, code-coverage, gcov

I want to generate a coverage report for my github [repo](https://github.com/jievince/nebula), it's a big C++ project built with CMake.

I add --coverage(equals to -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage) option to g++ build and link arguments in my [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/jievince/nebula/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), and I use gcov to generate code coverage data and upload the data to codecov.io.

These automated builds and tests are done in my Jenkins CI. The related code of Jenkins's execute shell is here:

```sh
cmake -DCODE_COVERAGE=ON -Dasan=OFF -DNEBULA_ASAN_PRELOAD= ..
make -j8
ctest -j8
    #generate code coverage report and upload it to codecov.io
TEST_FILES=$(find . -name '*.cpp.o')
    #gcov -abcr $TEST_FILES
for test_file in $TEST_FILES; do gcov -abcr $test_file; done
curl -s https://codecov.io/bash | bash -s - -t c85ebdca-ec7c-4301-a6ed-7967cf175db5
```

When Jenkins excutes *make -j8* and *ctest -j8*, and *gcov -abcr $test_file* I do get the related .gcno files, .gcda files, and gcov files. But when Jenkins excutes *curl -s https://codecov.io/bash | bash -s - -t c85ebdca-ec7c-4301-a6ed-7967cf175db5* to upload the data files to codecov,  the output seems strange. I see a lot of  similar errors like:

```sh
ExecutionPlan.gcno:'_ZNK6nebula4cpp29ValueType8get_typeEv' has arcs to entry block 
ExecutionPlan.gcno:'_ZNK6nebula4cpp29ValueType8get_typeEv' has arcs from exit block
```

And the -r option of gcov seems doesn't work because I also get a lot of coverage report of system header files.

And at the last the Jenkins tells me the build fails, so I can't see the coverage report in codecov.

Ps:

1. The source cpp files is not in the same directory with the .cpp.o(CMake's default C++ object type is .cpp.o not .o) files. And I do the above excute shell's code in the *build* directory, the .gcno, .gcda, and .gcov files are generated in the same directory.
2. Bucause the CMake's default object type is .cpp.o, the gcno and gcda files type generated is .cpp.gcno and .cpp.gcdas. So I use gcov filename.cpp.o insead of gcov filename.cpp which will tell me *couldn't open filename.gcno* errors.
3. I do some experiments to find the reason of errors.  I find when I give gcov one input file like *gcov 1.cpp.o*, I will get no *has arcs from exit block* errors, but when I give gcov more than one input files like *gcov 1.cpp.o 2.cpp.o* , I get the errors of *has arcs from exit block*. I think a probably reason is about combing multiple gcov files.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I'm curious why you tagged `cmake` in this question, as it does not seem to have anything to do with CMake? Also, when you run `gcov -r`, is the file `my.cpp` in the same directory?

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Hi, sorry for my misleading descriptions of my problem. I have edited my problem description. Please have a look at it.